# Categorize a numpy array of floats to corresponding integer index

Tags: python, numpy

I couldn't find a better way to phrase the question. I have this array `A`:

`0.1, 0.0, -0.2, -0.1, 0.1, 0.5`

I want to convert this to `B`:

`3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4`

Where each value of `B` is the index of the original float value in `np.unique(A)`.

Is there a convenient numpy (vectorized) way of doing it?

PS:

Another example, consider array `C`:

`[ 0.025, 0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.025, 0.075, -0.025, -0.075, 0.075, -0.075]`

Result of `np.unique(C)`:

`array([-0.075, -0.05 , -0.025,  0.   ,  0.025,  0.05 ,  0.075])`

I want to change `C` to `D`:

`[4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 6, 2, 0, 6]`

Notice that `-0.075` is the smallest value in `C` so it gets value `0` in `D`. Likewise, `0.075` is the largest value in `C` so it gets the largest value `6` in `D`.

Comment: Please be a bit more descriptive. Show another example, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the indices which would reconstruct the array `A`, i.e. the "inverse" of `unique`, use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the option `return_inverse=True`:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0.1, 0.0, -0.2, -0.1, 0.1, 0.5])
A_uniq, B = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)
print(B) # [3 2 0 1 3 4]
```

Comment: Well, that was embarrassingly simple. Thank you!

Comment: @Tharsalys No problem.